# Difference between a "Classic" biome and a "Together" one?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

In Don't Starve Together, I can generate two biomes : classic or together. Does anyone know the difference between those two options ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything from "Don't Starve: Reign Of Giants" is part of DST, with no option to turn it off. However, you can tell the map generator to generate your world as if it is vanilla Don't Starve. This turns all of the ROG specific biomes off, such as deciduous forest and desert, while still leaving in most of the ROG mechanics, such as seasons, moleworms, overheating, ROG specific items, etc.